# How can I validate a record only without saving in nodejs | sailsjs | waterline

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

I seek something of this nature

```
//validation rules in model "User"
attributes: {
    age: {
        required: true,
        type: 'numeric'
    }
},    

//now in controller, i want to be able to do this
Recipe.validate({age: 'An invalid age because it is a string. I except a validation error as response'});
```

Problem is, it doesn't work.. it complains about beforeValidate not being available, e.t.c

Comment: can't you build a Recipe instance, and simply not call its save function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a callback into `.validate`:

```
Recipe.validate({age: 'blah'}, function(err){
  if (err && err.invalidAttributes) {
    console.log(err.invalidAttributes); 
  } else {
    // model is valid
  }
});
```